# Laravel Validation: Custom rules on arrays (before_if)

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.4, laravel-validation

I am trying to write a custom before_if rule that mirrors the required_if rule. What I am trying to accomplish is making sure that the "primary" name on an account is not a minor (18+ years), but I am not quiet sure how to deal with this because I am looking at an array.

My rule looks like this

```
'names.*.birthdate' => 'required|date|before_if:-18 years,names.*.type,0' // Type 0 is primary name
```

However, I am not quite sure what to do in my extend logic. Specifically, I am not sure how to find the index of the current name I am on. I know this is possible because I already do this multiple times using required_if.

```
Validator::extend('before_if', function($attribute, $value, $parameters, $validator){
        // Not sure how to find the current index  
});
```

Comment: If I remember correctly laravel will expand an array into individual rules so you will probably have attributes like `names.X.birthdate` when evaluating the rule

Comment: @apokryfos You are correct, it does expand the original rules and replace the * with the correct for the name fields, but it leaves the * in the actual rule so my final rules array looks like 'names.0.birthdate' => 'required|date|before_if:-18 years,names.*.type,0'